# How to switch to two fragments of the same activity using intent in android java

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

i have **two fragments of the same activity(navigation drawer)** i added a button on one among them to switch to another but i am getting an error.i don't know how this works . please help me

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container,    false);

SwitchBtn= (AppCompatButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnswitch);

  // Register Button Click event
    SwitchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

  Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),

                    FriendsFragment.class);

            getActivity().startActivity(intent);

     }
    });
 }

   @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
      super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're switching between fragments, not starting a new activity.
Replace this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),

                FriendsFragment.class);

        getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

With this

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
             .replace(R.id.your_container_id, new FriendsFragment())
             .commit()
```

Comment: Thank you @Jagoan Neon you save my time and my life. cheer

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a fragment as such. What you need to do is either create them on the same activity, use a 'screen' variable that controls display by using the .setVisible on your components.

Or, what you can do is put your fragments on different activities using intent.

```
private Content C = getApplicationContext();
Intent myIntent = new Intent(C,yourActivity.class);
C.startActivity(myIntent);
```